# "Не теряю надежду"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "не теряю надежду" или "надежды"?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта верны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Старая ссылка: http://m.newslab.ru/blog/178928

Comment: А нормально, что по ссылке ничего не открывается, behemothus?