# Падеж с "не терять"

Tags: падежи

Как правильно сказать?

*Варианты:*

Необходимо хранить продукт так, чтобы он *не терял **своего вкуса***.
Необходимо хранить продукт так, чтобы он *не терял **свой вкус***.

Comment: Только не отсылайте меня сюда: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83. Здесь короткий ответ и неработающая ссылка, а хотелось бы попродробнее. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...Если существительное имеет отвлеченное значение: не теряет времени,
>   не испытывает желания, не скрывает радости.

А наш вкус-то (продукта-то) конкретный... Значит, винительный.

Так что правило не на падеж с "не терять", а на

[**Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/67-otr)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исчо тоньшее: [**Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием**](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/418/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC).

Comment: Спасибо, Галина!

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: А наш **вкус**-то (продукта-то) **конкретный**... Значит, винительный._ === ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ: **§ 1128... Конкретные существительные** - это слова, называющие вещи, лица, факты и все явления действительности, которые могут быть представлены в отдельности и подвергнуты счету: _карандаш, кольцо, инженер, поединок, война_. (http://rusgram.narod.ru/1121-1146.html)

Answer (score 1):

> ...не терял своего вкуса.
>
> ...не терял свой вкус.

По-моему, оба варианта правильны. Выбирайте на свой вкус. **Я бы выбрал первый.** Тем не менее...

> Варианты:
>
> Необходимо сохранить продукт, чтобы он *не терял **своего вкуса**.*
>
> Необходимо сохранить продукт, чтобы он *не терял **свой вкус***.

**Оба варианта плохи** (ИМХО). Можно чуть улучшить:

*Необходимо **хранить** продукт **так**, чтобы он не терял...*

А ещё лучше было бы во мн. ч.:

***Необходимо хранить продукты так, чтобы они не теряли...***

**P.S.**

Не зная контекста, не могу предложить большего.

Comment: Точно, Слава, спасибо, я тогда изменю на "хранить". Спасибо за ответ!