# Можно ли сказать: "не встречаЕтся упоминаниЯ о том событии"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Можно ли сказать: ***в тексте не встречаЕтся упоминаниЯ о том событии***?
(р. п. — чего? — упоминаниЯ)

Поспорили с преподавателем (не русского языка), который считает, что это ошибка. Он говорит, что надо либо ***не встречаЕтся упоминаниЕ*,** либо ***не встречаЮтся упоминаниЯ***, но никак не мой вариант.
Проблема в том, что теоретически никто доказать свою точку зрения не может.

Answer (score 5):

По-моему, Вы правы, и здесь нужен родительный падеж: *не встречается упоминани**я***. Аргументирую это.

Я уже задавал [близкий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419988/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C), и мне кажется, Ваш случай относится к 4-му пункту случаев, когда нужен родительный падеж, на скрине Галины, процитирую:

- **Если существительное имеет отвлечённое значение:** *не теряет времени, не испытывает желания, не скрывает радости.*

И ещё аргумент в пользу родительного падежа тот, что речь идёт не о конкретном упоминании, точнее нельзя здесь говорить об упоминании, о котором всё известно, то есть, например, как об упоминании, которое уже раньше видел и захотел ещё раз найти.

Comment: Тёмочка, пока я скринила Гугл-Книги, ты ответил об том же. ))) Но у меня пункт 5 в защиту родительного! Ещё надо разобраться (внизу ссылки) со всеми факультативами и "только р." / "только в.".

Comment: 5) То есть — так? ...(в беседе) не обнаруживается *понимания*, (в разлуке) не теряется *надежды*, (при встрече) не скрывается *радости*, (в учреждении) не осуществляется *контроля*, (при анализе) не упускается *случая*...

Comment: Ваши примеры отличаются от предложенного тем, что использованные существительные не сочетаются с применёнными безличными формами глаголов (в отличие от "не теряет надежды", "не скрывает радости", "не упускает контроля над чем-л."). Возможно, потому, что эти существительные не являются счётными в том смысле, что нельзя сказать "ни одной надежды", "ни одной радости", "ни одного контроля" - речь в таких выражениях может идти только о единственной сущности.

Comment: В случае же безусловно-счётного существительного "упоминание" проблемы с безличными глаголами нет: это выражение можно рассматривать напр. как упрощение от "не встречается ни одного (или: какого-либо) упоминания"; такое же значение будет иметь вариант множественного числа при родительном падеже: "не встречается упоминаний".

Comment: А в цитате Галины, Александр, к отвлеченным относятся "случай", "уступка", про которые можно сказать "ни одн(ого/ой)".

Comment: *В случае же безусловно-счётного существительного* - а это не критично. *На столе не лежало ни книги, ни тетради.*  *А без меня, а без меня здесь ничего бы не стояло* (c). Да можно и без "ни":  *"Меня там не было"*. *Больших проектов тогда институтом еще не разрабатывалось*. Не знаю, что должно произойти, чтобы эти фразы, даже последняя, были бы признаны грамматически ошибочными. О стилистике тут можно спорить, да. Но не о грамматике. Так что тут не в счетности существительного дело.

Comment: На всякий случай напишу "[близкий вопрос](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419988/Падеж-с-не-терять)" -- совсем не близкий, и правило, используемое там, совсем не имеет отношения к данному случаю. Там говорится о выборе падежа для глаголов, которые в случае отсутствия отрицания сочетаются с винительным падежом. В данном же случае ситуация совсем другая: в данном случае падеж **дополнения** может быть только родительный (не винительным) -- вопрос лишь в том, может ли "упоминание" быть в данном случае дополнением, т.е. может ли предложение быть безличным.

Answer (score 3):

У @Sasha в "зачеркнутом" (сиречь удаленном) дельная мысль проскочила. Действительно, сочетание отрицания в родительном падеже с возвратным (тем самым лишенным переходности) глаголом - это случай особый. Тем не менее он не только грамматически правилен, он единственно возможный. И дело, конечно, не в том, что "Вас тут не стояло" (*грамматически фраза, кстати, безупречна, комический эффект достигается не ошибкой, а пассивностью одушевленного объекта, что никакой грамматике не противоречит*). Тут именно непереходность глагола сказывается. Вот винительный падеж тут невозможен. Либо именительный - и тогда существительное оказывается в роли подлежащего, либо в безличной форме, тогда существительное здесь - дополнение и именно в родительном падеже.

Разберем для существительного женского рода, для которого a) именительный, винительный, родительный падеж различаются, б) личная форма глагола разная, если поставить в прошедшее время, отличается. Тогда всё станет ясно.

Возможно:
1) *Хорошая погода не ожидалась*. 
2) *Хорошей погоды не ожидалось*.

Третьего не дано. Вариант *хорошую погоду не ожидалось* - это не по-русски.

Так вот исходный вариант "не встречаЕтся упоминаниЯ" - это случай 2), не во множественном числе, а в безличной форме.

А "не встречаЕтся упоминаниЕ" - это именительный, соответствует случаю 1), хотя формы винительного и именительного тут омонимичны, а глагол в прошедшем времени все равно будет среднего рода, как и в безличном варианте. Или во множественном числе "не встречаЮтся упоминаниЯ" - тут форма существительного омонимична форме родительного падежа единственного числа.

И спасибо Sasha, хоть и зачеркнуто, но я разобрался в причинах сомнений.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Ваш спор с педагогом обозначается как [***Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием***](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/418/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC).

> ...**Р о д и т е л ь н ы й**    п а д е ж, имеющий в рассматриваемой
>   конструкции значение подчеркнутого отрицания, обычно употребляется:
>
> 5) при выражении дополнения отвлеченным существительным: не даёт
>   оснований, не обнаруживает понимания, не теряет надежды, не скрывает
>   радости, не осуществляет контроля, не упускает случая, не делает
>   уступок.

Вот несколько примеров из Гугл-Книги, правда, там присутствует наречие с *ни*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(при наличии в предложении частицы ни или местоимения либо наречия, в составе которых имеется указанная частица).

Посмотрите [все пункты по ссылке на правило](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/418/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) - там восемь случаев родительного, тринадцать винительного и сколько-то факультативного употребления...

Comment: А ведь Вы тоже не поняли смысла вопроса. Глагол-то непереходный.)))

Answer (score 1):

В таких неочевидных случаях можно долго спорить о верной грамматике, но, как мне кажется, лучше будет перефразировать:

> в тексте не встреча**Е**тся ни единого упоминани**Я**

Здесь уже поводов для сомнений не остаётся.

Answer (score 0):

Вкратце:

1. Так сказать можно.

   Просто варианты в виде обычного двусоставного предложения («не встречается упоминание» / «не встречаются упоминания») используются чаще, и человек, когда слышит начало «в тексте не встречается…», может быть подсознательно не готов к безличному предложению: он ожидает *подлежащее в именительном падеже*, а получает *дополнение в родительном* — и это может показаться ему ошибкой.

   <sub>Разные варианты:

   • Не встречается *(и.п., ед.ч., подл.)* упоминание. *⟵ двусост. предл.*

   • Не встречаются *(и.п., мн.ч., подл.)* упоминания. *⟵ двусост. предл.*

   • Мы не встречаем *(р.п., ед.ч., доп.)* упоминания. *⟵ двусост. предл.*

   • Мы не встречаем *(р.п., мн.ч., доп.)* упоминаний. *⟵ двусост. предл.*

   • Не встречено *(р.п., ед.ч., доп.)* упоминания. *⟵ безл. предл.*

   • Не встречено *(р.п., мн.ч., доп.)* упоминаний. *⟵ безл. предл.*

   • **Не встречается** *(р.п., ед.ч., доп.)* **упоминания.** *⟵ безл. предл.*

   • Не встречается *(р.п., ед.ч., доп.)* упоминаний. *⟵ безл. предл.*</sub>
2. Примеры из национального корпуса русского языка, аналогичные по форме Вашему варианту:

   - Н. Арапова. «Подводные камни» в русской классике // «Наука и жизнь», 2006:

     > Но такого терминологического словосочетания в текстах XIX века не встречается.
   - Сергей Филатов. «Мячи, в которые играли боги» // «Зеркало мира», 2012:

     > Итак, ни в одной из авторитетных научных работ не встречается утверждения о «точности в пределах 2 мм».
   - В. А. Успенский. Математическое и гуманитарное: преодоление барьера (2007-2011):

     > В окружающем нас материальном мире плотных порядков не встречается.
3. Аргументация в ответах @Galina Avanesova и @Артём Луговой неверна.

   Они пытаются опереться на правило ([[1]](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/418/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC), [[2]](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/67-otr)) выбора падежа дополнения при отрицании переходного глагола (т.е. глагола, который в случае без отрицания стыкуется с существительным в винительном падеже: «я вижу доску» → «я не вижу доску/доски»). Но оно здесь ни при чём, потому что «встречаться» — непереходный глагол (то что, во фразе «встречается упоминание» кому-то может показаться, что «упоминание» — это дополнение в винительном падеже, — это иллюзия, «упоминание» в ней — это подлежащее в именительном).

---

<s>Нельзя!</s>

Это из серии "Вас тут не слояло!".

Правильно:

> В тексте (нам) не встречается упоминани**е** о том событии.
>   В тексте мы не встречаем упоминани**я** о том событии.

1. @Galina Avanesova:

   > Вот несколько примеров из Гугл-Книги, правда, там присутствует наречие с ни: [[...]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIl8R.png).

   Получается, это распространённая ошибка.
2. @Galina Avanesova:

   > [Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/418/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC).

   Это не относится к данной ситуации по одной простой причине: "встречаться" не переходный глагол. Оно вообще никак не соотносится с винительным падежом, попробуйте-ка на вкус: `В баре мне встретилось ковбоя.` или `В статье встречается метафоры.`. То что, во фразе `В книге встречается упоминание о [...].` Вам кажется, что `упоминание` стоит в винительном падеже -- это чистая иллюзия, оно стоит в *именительном* (`упоминание` -- это подлежащее, а `встречается` -- это сказуемое).
3. @Galina Avanesova:

   > [Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/67-otr)

   @Артём Луговой:

   > - Если существительное имеет отвлечённое значение: не теряет времени, не испытывает желания, не скрывает радости.

   Ну тут, в принципе, всё то же. Хоть они и явно не говорят про переходные глаголы, но вдумайтесь: они же выбирают между ''родительным'' и ''винительным'' падежами. Родительным и винительным, Карл! Если бы они выбирали между именительным и родительным, то их правило можно было бы читать и думать, подходит ли оно нам, а так....

Post Scriptum. Я не исключаю, что говорить "Вас тут не стояло" и "в баре мне не встретилось ни одного ковбоя" скоро станет нормой. Русский язык меняется, и это нормально. (Главное не давить слишком на людей, которые используют новый, пока ещё ненормативный вариант, чтобы не происходили неприятные ситуации по аналогии со словами `ложить` и `звонит`.)

Comment: Зачем зачеркивать-то?